# Change svg line co-ordinates using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change x1,x2,y1,y2 of my svg line using javascript.

```
var t=document.getElementsByTagName("line")[0];
t.x1="20"; t.y1="75"; t.x2="430"; t.y2="75";
```

But, this does not work. Do I have to use `setAttribute()` method?

Comment: Yes, `setAttribute()` should work. Did you try it?

Comment: Don't you need to access the SVG DOM first, like doc = yourSVG.contentDocument; and then go on from there?

Comment: @axel.michel I already go to line element so I don't think I need to access svg first.

Comment: @FabianSchultz yes, it works.

Comment: I think https://css-tricks.com/presentation-attributes-vs-inline-styles/ might be what you are looking for